# How to get file_id from StickerSet in pyrogram?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, pyrogram

To send sticker with pyrogram I need to use:

```
await message.reply_sticker(sticker_file_id)
```

So I need get random file_id of sticker pack to send sticker.

```
sticker_set = await client.invoke(
    GetStickerSet(
        stickerset=InputStickerSetShortName(short_name="HotCherry"),
        hash=0
    )
)

sticker = random.choice(sticker_set.documents)
print(sticker)
```

But I have sticker object without file_id:

```
{
    "_": "types.Document",
    "id": 1391391008142393351,
    "access_hash": -4097529056751820472,
    "file_reference": "b'\\x00c\\xaf.7.O3 \\x04\\x81\\xf00y\\xbd\\x82\\x1bV\\x7f\\xc8n'",
    "date": 1561820428,
    "mime_type": "application/x-tgsticker",
    "size": 9526,
    "dc_id": 2,
    "attributes": [
        {
            "_": "types.DocumentAttributeImageSize",
            "w": 512,
            "h": 512
        },
        {
            "_": "types.DocumentAttributeSticker",
            "alt": "",
            "stickerset": {
                "_": "types.InputStickerSetID",
                "id": 1391391008142393345,
                "access_hash": 3354279076546271904
            },
            "mask": false
        },
        {
            "_": "types.DocumentAttributeFilename",
            "file_name": "AnimatedSticker.tgs"
        }
    ],
    "thumbs": [
        {
            "_": "types.PhotoPathSize",
            "type": "j",
            "bytes": "b'\\x14\\x05\\xae\\t\\xdc|\\x81K\\x08NO\\t|F\\x06G\\x05jS\\x00\\xabW\\t\\x93K\\xaaR\\x86\\x04U\\x86\\x81\\x8d\\x81\\x92A\\x85C\\x86W\\x86[\\x80]Qum|DAgBaM\\x81C\\x86F\\x88H\\x9f`\\x87\\x02\\x8a\\x88\\x08\\xa5\\x86\\x8b\\x98\\x86\\x08\\x9c\\x87\\x01\\x8d\\x8b\\x9e\\x8a\\xaf\\x8f\\xa4\\x8b\\x86\\x06\\xa1\\x88\\x05\\x86\\x06\\xbe\\x8a\\t_\\x98\\x02O\\x00\\x98\\x00'"
        },
        {
            "_": "types.PhotoSize",
            "type": "m",
            "w": 128,
            "h": 128,
            "size": 4218
        }
    ],
    "video_thumbs": []
}
```

How I can send random sticker from sticker pack if I know only sticker pack name(sticker_set)?

Comment: Look to this answer on [official telegram group](https://t.me/pyrogramchat/498055)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, to @Muhammadyusuf answer in comment I solve this problem by using this code(which is not recommended as is using protected method):

```
from pyrogram.types import Sticker
from pyrogram import raw, Client, errors
   
bot = Client(...)
    
async def parse_a_pack(shortName):
    try:
        info = await bot.invoke(raw.functions.messages.GetStickerSet(stickerset=raw.types.InputStickerSetShortName(short_name=shortName),hash=0))
    except errors.StickersetInvalid:
        return []
    
    documents = info.documents
    final = []
    for stk in documents:
        sticker = await Sticker._parse(bot, stk, {type(i): i for i in stk.attributes})
        final.append(sticker)
    return final
```